# Find the closest ancestor commit to an estranged code base

Tags: git

I am working on an old project that I have inherited without version control information.  The project was forked from a Git repository at some point in the past and has diverged.  I have no documentation, changelogs or anything else to indicate when it was forked or what changes have been made.  As a concrete example, imagine I have done something akin to this:

```
git clone project
git checkout vx.y.z
patch < my_changes
rm -rf .git
```

How can I work out what is the closest ancestor commit of the project to my current codebase, so I can start to work out how and why it has diverged?

Comment: Try checking files change times, maybe you will find some old not changed files. Then you can look around that date to see if there is any commits. Or try comparing some files contents

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+closest+commit

Comment: Thank you, @phd, that's pretty much what I was after.